# BackgroundTask iOS 13 Swift with Scenes

Tags: swift, ios13

I am trying to implement the new iOS 13 background tasks functionality with  a new app that is utilizing Scenes (also new).  There are not a lot of examples, but the ones I have found were not using SceneDelegates, instead all the logic was contained in the AppDelegate.   This causes issues since the event for the app going into the background is now raised in the SceneDelegate, not the AppDelegate.

This method does not fire in AppDelegate when using scenes

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

}
```

This method does fire in SceneDelegate

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {

}
```

I am not able to find a corresponding SceneDelegate method for the following method in AppDelegate where all the examples show BGTaskScheduler registering tasks

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "UNIQUE_ID", using: DispatchQueue.global()) { task in
            refreshMethod(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }

}
```

My question is whether there is some event in the SceneDelegate where I can register the task and if not what is the recommended pattern to follow for scene based apps.

Comment: Any thoughts on this?  Any feedback on why I got down voted?

Answer (score 0):

`AppDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is still called at app launch, even when you have a SceneDelegate. So you should continue to register your background tasks in that method.